# Sharepoint 2016: failed to create configuration database although necessary database permissions set

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, windows-server-2012-r2, development-enviroment, sql-server-2016

I am running Sharepoint 2016 on a domain controller, running Windows Server 2012 R2. It is running in a development environment as a single-server with SQL Server 2016. I have installed Sharepoint Server 2016, but am experiencing the following error when running through the Sharepoint Products Configuration Wizard at the end:

```
Configuration Failed

Failed to create the configuration database.

An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown. Additional exception information: One or more types failed to load.
```

The link to the detailed log file with the error is here: [Sharepoint Products Configuration Wizard trace log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/969f7f83309a1a6b5d09766a83f64758).

I have run the Sharepoint Products Configuration Wizard using the administrator account and this account has the dbcreator, sysadmin and securityadmin server roles set, yet I am still experiencing the above error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: did you use the same account when you create the config wizard? the place where you enter configdb name and user name and password?

Comment: Yes, I used the same administrator account (mydomainname\administrator) in the config wizard, where you enter the configdb name and username and password.

Comment: In other cases, you should install WCF Services Tools using prerequisites installer. Check the details at [SharePoint 2016: Failed to create the configuration database. An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/05/21/sharepoint-2016-failed-to-create-the-configuration-database-an-exception-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-upgrade-spupgradeexception-was-thrown/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unblocked the Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.6 executable (which is part of the Sharepoint 2016 prerequisites) as stated in the [Microsoft TechNet blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2016/04/15/spupgradeexception-error-message-when-you-run-the-sharepoint-products-and-technologies-configuration-wizard-when-you-create-a-new-sharepoint-2016-farm/). I then did a repair install, followed by running the Sharepoint Products Configuration Wizard again. This resulted in the configuration wizard completing successfully.